# Auto volume leveling with Windows Media Player 12

Tags: audio, automation, mp3, windows-media-player, volume-mixer

It seems that it was possible before using a WMP Enhancement, but the [manual][1] I found seems to be for an older version, since I can't find this option in WMP 12.

[![Screenshot][2]][2]

Is it still possible to play different audio files with different volume levels automatically normalized?

[1]: http://On%20https://www.windows-media-player.com/set-up-the-same-volume-level/#:~:text=1)%20In%20Windows%20Media%20Player,in%20the%20following%20screen%20shot.
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/urKM6.png

Comment: Somehow, the screenshot does not appear, but you can click on the [2] link to view it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, these enhancements are still available in WMP 12. First make sure that you're in Now Playing mode - if you're still in Library mode click the button in the lower right corner to switch to Now Playing. Then right-click in an empty area and select `Enhancements` - `Crossfading and auto volume levelling`.

Comment: Thanks! I was looking in the wrong place...

Comment: Sometimes they are there, but not available - do you know the reason for this?

Comment: What exactly do you mean with not available? Would it be possible to post a screenshot?